# Obtener objeto de controlador en la vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

como le hago para obtener y manipular un objeto que regreso con la vista desde el controlador. este es el codigo

```
public ActionResult CargarDiesel(int id)
    {
        var equipo = (from eq in db.equipos
                      join cd in db.cargasDiesel on eq.id equals cd.equiposId
                      where eq.id == id
                      select new { eq, cd });
        return View(equipo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que decirle a tu `view` con que modelo esta trabajando, para esto defines el modelo con `Razor` de la siguiente manera:

```
@using TuNamespace.Models
@model TuNamespace.Models.TuObjeto
```

La primera linea es para tener acceso al espacio de nombres donde se encuentran tus modelos (o el modelo al que quieres acceder) la segunda linea es la que le dice al `View` que trabajara con ese modelo en especifico.

A partir de ahi `@Model` contendra el objeto que regresaste del controlador, para acceder a sus propiedades es tan facil como hacer `@Model.Propiedad` y lo puedes usar como usarias cualquier variable en `Razor`

```
<h1>Id: @Model.Id</h1>
```

**Actualizacion**

En caso de que no se tenga un modelo para el objeto que se regresara del controlador, la manera mas simple de solucionarlo es crear un `ViewModel` que no es mas que una clase que contiene las propiedades que utilizaras en tu `View`. La utilizacion es la misma, solo debes cambiar las primeras lineas para buscar el `ViewModel` en lugar del `Model` y quedaria algo asi:

```
@using TuNamespace.ViewModels
@model TuNamespace.ViewModels.TuViewModel
```

Comment: Y si es un modelo que no esta definido que puedo hacer? es decir, el modeo equipos y cargasDiesel si esta definido, pero quiero regresar lo que me regresa la consulta. gracias

Comment: Ve la actualizacion de la respueta.